# how to duplex-print with a HP OfficeJet 6700

Tags: printing, cups

I am using SUSE Linux 13.2 with an HP OfficeJet 6700.

I want to duplex-print on DIN A4 paper (German industry norm, about the "letter" size in US, to be exact 210x297 millimetres). This is not possible without illegal margins. I am calling margins illegal if information that should get printed gets lost. I even blogged about it here: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/HP_OfficeJet_6700

The situation is as follows:

- printing a test page on DIN A4, non-duplex, with hpijs driver works well (3x13 mm legal margin)
- printing a test page on DIN A4, non-duplex, with hpcups driver works great (3x3 mm legal margin)
- printing from libreOffice (set to paper size of DIN A4) and hpcups driver: illegal margins
- printing from libreOffice (set to paper size of DIN A4) and hpijs driver: no illegal margins
- duplex print: illegal margins in every case listed above

There are the following paper size settings that seem plausible for my situation:

- A4 210x297mm
- A4 Borderless 210x297mm
- Index Card A4 210x297mm
- A4 AutoDuplex 210x297mm
- Custom

but non of them, even not "custom" makes the illegal margins go away as long as I choose duplex print (long edge).

Do you have a solution or maybe just a step for troubleshooting this further? What application would I use to print a "real" test page (as the cups test page obviously does not represent what applications send to the printer)?